# how to loacate a polygon on canvas using Selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas, vaadin7, polygons

how to locate a `polygon` on `canvas` using `selenium` with `java` ? I want to click on the `polygon`

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='intelsysbindingwebwebapp-1032693235-overlays']/a[1]")).click();
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='intelsysbindingwebwebapp-1032693235-overlays']/a[1]")).click(); <iframe id> is outside the div tag and script src also provided